# List of Abbreviations headline not same font size as List of Tables

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I just started using Latex and I'm stuck already. I tried to find solutions online but I couldn't find the right one.

In my document I want to make a list of abbreviations, so I used the acronym package. The list is being generated the way I want it to but the headline ('List of Abbreviations') has a smaller font size than the headlines of the list of figures and list of tables.

All three are subsections but for some reason `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` use a larger font size than the usual subsections. Making my list of abbr. a section (instead of a subsection). On the other hand, would put it on the wrong level in the TOC, so that's no solution.

I'd appreciate some ideas. Thanks in advance.

This should display my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}           
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[]{acronym}  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\vspace{4cm}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Abbreviations}

\subsection*{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}[bash]
    \acro{T1}{Test1}
    \acro{T2}{Test2}
    \acro{T3}{Test3}
\end{acronym}               

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help. If I use sections instead of subsections the problem gets solved, but I would like to make the lists in the toc look different than numbered sections that I'm about to add (like introduction). Is it possible to make some sections not be bold in the toc?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}           
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[]{acronym}  

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \vspace{4cm}

    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}

    \section*{List of Abbreviations}
    \begin{acronym}[bash]
        \acro{T1}{Test1}
        \acro{T2}{Test2}
        \acro{T3}{Test3}
    \end{acronym}               

    \section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, use `\section*{List of Abbreviations}` as the toc, the lof and the lot are printed as sections as well.

Comment: Johannes, thanks for your response. That's a nice workaround, but I prefer to have the different lists on the subsection level in the toc. Otherwise they would be on the same level as Introduction,..., and conclusion which would take the reader's focus away from those..

Comment: Well, on the other hand it makes sense to do it the way you proposed since otherwise I would also have to make the references look like a subsection in the toc. Ok. So, if I declare these lists as sections, is there a way to make them look different to other sections (e.g. not bold)?

Comment: The example you gave uses `section`s for toc and lof and lot, please compile the example. It is possible though, that there is more going on in your document and you left that part out.

Comment: When I run the code I wrote above, it makes 'List of Abbreviations' smaller than the other lists. Your idea solved this issue. However when I add generic sections to the code (introduction, etc) they (naturally) have the same fontstyle. Now I would like to graphically separate these sections from the lists. Wait, I'll add code to my original question, to make my request more visible.

Comment: That would involve redefining internals, quite a lot of them. You might get better result using `scrartcl`, where you can set the option `listof=leveldown` to print all lists (defined by KOMA) as a subsection. Getting them to the table of contents is just as easy. No manual error prone fiddling.

Answer (score 1):

What yo are looking for is the `leveldown` feature of KOMA-script.

[image: hansmaulwurfKomaLeveldown]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,listof=leveldown,listof=totoc,]{scrartcl}           
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[]{acronym}  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newcommand{\listacroname}{List of Abbreviations}
\subsection*{\listacroname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\listacroname}
\begin{acronym}[bash]
    \acro{T1}{Test1}
    \acro{T2}{Test2}
    \acro{T3}{Test3}
\end{acronym}               

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, you might have just misunderstood me and want this, though i cannot recommend this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}           
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[]{acronym}  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Figures} \listoftables
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Tables}

\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}[bash]
    \acro{T1}{Test1}
    \acro{T2}{Test2}
    \acro{T3}{Test3}
\end{acronym}               

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well the last one is indeed the solution to my original problem, so technically my question is answered. Unfortunately this will cause further issues: When I add additional unnumbered subsections (e.g. references), they could be confused as subsections of the section prior to them (e.g. conclusion). But these are minor issues and I'm not going to bother you with this anymore. **Thanks for all your help!!!** :-) I might change the document to a KOMA class now.